# Optimal way to compute pairwise mutual information using numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, information-theory

For an *m x n* matrix, what's the optimal (fastest) way to compute the mutual information for all pairs of columns (*n x n*)?

By [mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information), I mean:

> *I(X, Y) = H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y)*

where *H(X)* refers to the Shannon entropy of *X*.

Currently I'm using `np.histogram2d` and `np.histogram` to calculate the joint *(X,Y)* and individual *(X or Y)* counts. For a given matrix `A` (e.g. a 250000 X 1000 matrix of floats), I am doing a nested `for` loop,

```
n = A.shape[1]
for ix = arange(n)  
    for jx = arange(ix+1,n):
       matMI[ix,jx]= calc_MI(A[:,ix],A[:,jx])
```

Surely there must be better/faster ways to do this?

As an aside, I've also looked for mapping functions on columns (column-wise or row-wise operations) on arrays, but haven't found a good general answer yet.

Here is my full implementation, following the conventions in [the Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information):

```
import numpy as np
 
def calc_MI(X,Y,bins):
 
    c_XY = np.histogram2d(X,Y,bins)[0]
    c_X = np.histogram(X,bins)[0]
    c_Y = np.histogram(Y,bins)[0]
 
    H_X = shan_entropy(c_X)
    H_Y = shan_entropy(c_Y)
    H_XY = shan_entropy(c_XY)
 
    MI = H_X + H_Y - H_XY
    return MI
 
def shan_entropy(c):
    c_normalized = c / float(np.sum(c))
    c_normalized = c_normalized[np.nonzero(c_normalized)]
    H = -sum(c_normalized* np.log2(c_normalized))  
    return H
 
A = np.array([[ 2.0,  140.0,  128.23, -150.5, -5.4  ],
              [ 2.4,  153.11, 130.34, -130.1, -9.5  ],
              [ 1.2,  156.9,  120.11, -110.45,-1.12 ]])
 
bins = 5 # ?
n = A.shape[1]
matMI = np.zeros((n, n))
 
for ix in np.arange(n):
    for jx in np.arange(ix+1,n):
        matMI[ix,jx] = calc_MI(A[:,ix], A[:,jx], bins)
```

Although my working version with nested `for` loops does it at reasonable speed, I'd like to know if there is a more optimal way to apply `calc_MI` on all the columns of `A` (to calculate their pairwise mutual information)?

I'd also like to know:

1. Whether there are efficient ways to map functions to operate on columns (or rows) of `np.arrays` (maybe like `np.vectorize`, which looks more like a decorator)?
2. Whether there are other optimal implementations for this specific calculation (mutual information)?

Comment: since i see ```histogram2d``` being used, are we talking about discretized entropy here, not differential entropy? If so, what binning strategy is being used and how is the binning method identifiable from the code?

Answer (score 76):

I can't suggest a faster calculation for the outer loop over the n*(n-1)/2
vectors, but your implementation of `calc_MI(x, y, bins)` can be simplified
if you can use scipy version 0.13 or [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html).

In scipy 0.13, the `lambda_` argument was added to [`scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html)
This argument controls the statistic that is computed by the function.  If
you use `lambda_="log-likelihood"` (or `lambda_=0`), the log-likelihood ratio
is returned.  This is also often called the G or G<sup>2</sup> statistic.  Other than
a factor of 2*n (where n is the total number of samples in the contingency
table), this *is* the mutual information.  So you could implement `calc_MI`
as:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

def calc_MI(x, y, bins):
    c_xy = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins)[0]
    g, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(c_xy, lambda_="log-likelihood")
    mi = 0.5 * g / c_xy.sum()
    return mi
```

The only difference between this and your implementation is that this
implementation uses the natural logarithm instead of the base-2 logarithm
(so it is expressing the information in "nats" instead of "bits").  If
you really prefer bits, just divide `mi` by log(2).

If you have (or can install) `sklearn` (i.e. scikit-learn), you can use
[`sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score.html), and implement `calc_MI` as:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score

def calc_MI(x, y, bins):
    c_xy = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins)[0]
    mi = mutual_info_score(None, None, contingency=c_xy)
    return mi
```

Comment: Nice code! What is a reasonable default value for number of bins?

Comment: @felbo That's a good question, and not one that can be easily answered.  You might get some ideas if you ask it over at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This method does not work if some counts equal zero. Why do you suggest this method over density estimation? Also, I upvoted your answer as it does provide an efficient way to calculate MI for some scenarios.

Comment: *"Why do you suggest this method over density estimation?"* I didn't.  I only suggested a couple alternative implementations of the code given in the question.

Comment: The two suggested methods differs by continuity correction. Change to  `chi2_contingency(correction = False)` removes this inconsistency.

Comment: [Beware](https://kaushikghose.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/computing-mutual-information-and-other-scary-things/) of discretization (ie the bin sizes). This blog recommends the "Jack Knifed Estimate" to overcome this, or I would also expect density estimator techniques to help.

Comment: what's the difference between this implementation and https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html?highlight=mutual_info_classif#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif ?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the outer loop (sort of), one way is to rewrite `calc_MI` to call the vectorized functions used in the construction of `matMI` on the entire array of `c_XY`s.

`shan_entropy` uses functions that can work on arrays of any size and `c_X` and `c_Y` are the marginal totals across the second and first dimensions of the output of `np.histogram2d`, respectively. Also the looped assignment to `matMI` may be done in vectorized fashion using `np.triu_indices`.

The only unavoidable loop here is the loop over pairs of columns of `A` to call `np.histogram2d` but that part can be parallelized using `joblib.Parallel`.

```py
def shan_entropy(c):
    return - (c * np.log2(c, out=np.zeros(c.shape), where=(c!=0))).sum(axis=1)

def calc_pairwise_mutual_info(A, bins):
    
    m, n = A.shape
    matMI = np.zeros((n, n))

    c_XYs = np.array([np.histogram2d(A[:,ix], A[:,jx], bins)[0] for ix in range(n-1) for jx in range(ix+1, n)]) / m
    c_Xs = c_XYs.sum(axis=2)
    c_Ys = c_XYs.sum(axis=1)
    c_XYs = c_XYs.reshape(len(c_XYs), -1)

    H_X, H_Y, H_XY = map(shan_entropy, (c_Xs, c_Ys, c_XYs))

    MI = H_X + H_Y - H_XY
    matMI[np.triu_indices(n, k=1)] = MI
    return matMI


A = np.array([[ 2.0,  140.0,  128.23, -150.5, -5.4  ],
              [ 2.4,  153.11, 130.34, -130.1, -9.5  ],
              [ 1.2,  156.9,  120.11, -110.45,-1.12 ]])

bins = 5

MI_arr = calc_pairwise_mutual_info(A, bins)
```

You can verify that `MI_arr` is the same (`np.allclose` returns True) as `matMI` as computed in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [scipy.stat.entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34551445)