# faster histogram2d calculations in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, histogram2d

I have a code that calculates entropies for joint distributions and am using histogram2d to calculate **pairwise ** joint entropies of all columns for matrices of size 20000 x 300 (& such large datasets) ie., n * n-1/2 calculations

Most of the time is spent in calculating the joint counts. A simple cProfiling reveals the following costly functions :

```
   histogram2d ->  histogramdd -> atleast_2d -> asarray -> numpy.core.multiarray.array
       87%            85%     |       40%          38%             39%
                              |-->  digitize
                                      10 %
```

I thought np.digitize was the one doing most of the work for counting. But seems like a good chunk of the time is being take by other functions like asarray!  Could someone point how to make these calculations faster, in a easier way! (ie., obviously not point me to write the histogram function in C/C++ ? )

Thanks in advance.  This question is related to the calculation of MI that I posted earlier : 
[Optimal way to compute pairwise mutual information using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491028/optimal-way-for-calculating-columnwise-mutual-information-using-numpy)

Comment: This is only a guess, but it looks like that your input isn't the format expected by histogram2d and thus requires a conversion before it could be used. If you look at the source in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html the calls to `atleast_2d` happened as a copy _unless_ it doesn't match the expected shape.

Comment: Thanks @Hooked .. will check it out. as it is am passing vectors and matrices only. is there any casting i could do to ensure data type ?

Comment: The best way for us to help you is to post a _minimal working example_ that shows your problem. If it a data type issue there is no way we could diagnose it with the information given here.

Comment: Thanks @Hooked. Here I had posted one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491028/optimal-way-for-calculating-columnwise-mutual-information-using-numpy