# What methods return a single measure of similarity between two functions?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

The functions in this case are discrete data sets. I do not have actual functions.

I have two cases. One is where the data sets appear as approximately parallel lines. The more complex case is where the lines share a similar slope but are shifted along the x-axis.

I tried numpy.correlate, but the output is not a single number. I'm also not sure how this method could work given that the points where the data are sampled on the x-axis are not always the same.

I also tried using numpy.fft.rfft to take the Fourier transform of the two, normalized functions. I then used numpy.fft.irfft on the product of the two transformed functions. This is also returning a function rather than a single measure of similarity.

I'm looking for the simplest, most efficient way to obtain a single number representing the measure of similarity between two data sets sampled over a similar space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like this (I mean all your points lie along two parallel lines):
[image]

Then you can сalculate line coefficients y=a*x+b by the least squares method. And similarity between lines y<sub>1</sub> and y<sub>2</sub> will be simply |b<sub>1</sub> - b<sub>2</sub>|

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge generally, there are two approaches: correlation and mutual information.

In numpy, use [`numpy.corrcoef`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) for Pearson (simple) correlation. For Spearman rank correlation, use [`scipy.stats.spearmanr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html) from `scipy`.

For mutual information, check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491028/optimal-way-for-calculating-columnwise-mutual-information-using-numpy)

To see if you functions `f1` and `f2` need mutual information, or Pearson correlation is fine, plot your points in a scatter plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(f1, f2)
plt.show()
```

if they form more or less straight cloud along a line, then Pearson should work. Otherwise try Spearman and mutual information