# Normalized Mutual Information by Scikit Learn giving me wrong value

Tags: python

I’m new in Python and I’m trying to see the normalized mutual information between 2 different signals, and no matter what signals I use, the result I obtain is always 1, which I believe it’s impossible because the signals are different and not totally correlated.

I’m using the [Normalized Mutual Information Function provided Scikit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score.html#sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score): sklearn.metrics.normalized mutualinfo_score(labels_true, labels_pred).

Here’s the code I’m using:

```
from numpy.random import randn
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import normalized_mutual_info_score as mi
import pandas as pd

def fzX(X):
''' z-scoring columns'''
if len(X.shape)>1:
    '''X is matrix ... more vars'''
    meanX=mean(X,0)
    stdX=std(X,0)
    stdX[stdX<1e-9]=0
    zX=zeros(X.shape)
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        if stdX[i]>0:
            zX[:,i]=(X[:,i]-meanX[i])/stdX[i]
        else:
            zX[:,i]=0
else:
    '''X is vector ... more vars'''
    meanX=mean(X)
    stdX=std(X,0)
    zX=(X-meanX)/stdX
return(zX,meanX,stdX)

def fMI(X):
'''vars in columns,
   returns mut info of normalized data'''
zX,meanX,stdX=fzX(X)
n=X.shape[1]
Mut_Info=zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        Mut_Info[i,j]=mi(zX[:,i],zX[:,j])
        Mut_Info[j,i]=Mut_Info[i,j]
plot(zX);show()
return(Mut_Info)

t=arange(0,100,0.1)  # t=0:0.1:99.9
N=len(t)  # number of samples in t
u=sin(2*pi*t)+(randn(N)*2)**2
y=(cos(2*pi*t-2))**2+randn(N)*2

X=zeros((len(u),2))
X[:,0]=u
X[:,1]=y

mut=fMI(X)
print mut

plot(X)
show()
```

Did anyone of you have similar problem before? Do you know what I’m doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance for your dedicated time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your floating point data can't be used this way -- [`normalized_mutual_info_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score.html#sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score) is defined over *clusters*. The function is going to interpret every floating point value as a distinct cluster. And if you look back at the documentation, you'll see that the function throws out information about cluster labels. After all, the labels themselves are arbitrary, so anti-correlated labels have as much mutual information as correlated labels.

**Examples**

Here are a couple of examples based directly on the documentation:

```
>>> normalized_mutual_info_score([1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0])
1.0
>>> normalized_mutual_info_score([1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1])
1.0
```

See how the labels are perfectly correlated in the first case, and perfectly anti-correlated in the second? But in both cases, the mutual information is `1.0`. The same pattern continues for partially correlated values:

```
>>> normalized_mutual_info_score([1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1])
0.34559202994421129
>>> normalized_mutual_info_score([1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0])
0.34559202994421129
```

Swapping the labels just in the second sequence has no effect. And again, this time with floating point values:

```
>>> normalized_mutual_info_score([0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5])
0.34559202994421129
>>> normalized_mutual_info_score([0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1])
0.34559202994421129
```

So having seen all that, this shouldn't seem so surprising:

```
>>> normalized_mutual_info_score([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8])
1.0
```

Each floating point is considered its own label, but the labels are themselves arbitrary. So the function can't tell any difference between the two sequences of labels, and returns `1.0`.

**Working with floating point data**

If you're starting out with floating point data, and you need to do this calculation, you probably want to *assign* cluster labels, perhaps by putting points into bins using two different schemes.

For example, in the first scheme, you could put every value `p <= 0.5` in cluster `0` and `p > 0.5` in cluster `1`. Then, in the second scheme, you could put every value `p <= 0.4` in cluster `0` and `p > 0.4` in cluster `1`. These clusterings would mostly overlap; the points where they did not would cause the mutual information score to go down.

There are other possible clustering schemes -- I'm not quite sure what your goal is, so I can't give more concrete advice than that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the enlightenment.

Do you know any way to find out the mutual information between two signals with floating point values?

Comment: [francesco](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2983863/francesco) suggested that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20505476) shows how to compute the mutual information for continuous variables.

Comment: Thanks francesco for drawing my attention to the new comment from @AntónioCova. But unless I misunderstand, it's still not the "mutual information for continuous variables". See my edited answer for more details.